# Calling a controller function within a Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need your help about an AngularJS issue: I'm creating a Directive to manage a customer/offices situation (two select boxes, one for customers and one for offices related to the customer selected). When I load the html page containing the directive I must check if an officeID "is present" and, in that case, fill the html selects with the right values based on that officeID. To do so I must call a function in the controller of the directive. This is my directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive('myCustomersOffices', ["ConstantsService", 
    function(ConstantsService){

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            office : '='
        },
        controller : 'customersOfficesController',
        templateUrl: ConstantsService.URL.BASE_APP+'/bundles/customers/views/customersOffices.html',
        link : function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!
            //Here I would like to call getOfficesByOfficeID(officeID), a function
            //contained in the controller 
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    };

}]);
```

This is my html directive template:

```
<div id="customer-and-offices">
    <select class="form-control" id="activity-customers"
            data-ng-change="getOffices(selectedCustomer)" data-ng-options="customer.ID as customer.name for customer in customers" data-ng-model="selectedCustomer">
        <option value="">Choose customer...</option>

    </select>

    <select class="form-control" id="activity-offices"
            data-ng-options="office.ID as office.name for office in customerOffices" data-ng-model="office">
        <option value="">Choose office...</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and this is the way I call the directive in the main html page:

```
<my-customers-offices office="activity.get().officeID"></my-customers-offices>
```

All the stuff that you can read above works properly to retrieve the office starting from the customer selection (the "normal" case). But, as I said, I would like to call a function getOfficeByOffice if an officeID "is present" when the html main page "is ready". How can I pass the possible officeID to the link directive function? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can pass the desired controller function into your directive using the ampersand isolate scope specification. Great explanation on usage [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-expression-binding).

Comment: You can add the "getOfficesByOfficeID" function to a service and pass the service reference to the directive using dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, it's a bad idea to have methods in your controllers. I'd advise that you create service modules that contain functions that can be shared across directives and controllers. Then its only a matter of injecting the the module (and the service) anywhere in your main application.

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8hWL/) that is somewhat close to what you want.

The code:

```
'use strict';

var module = angular.module("myApp", [])

.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.variable = "this";
})

.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        template: '{{variable}} is accessible here, so are functions.'
    };
});
```

And the HTML;

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```